# C# How to ensure thread safe when setting external class property 'string` and calling method

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I am working on code performance optimizing. I have implemented `Task.WhenAll` in `MethodA`. In `MethodA` I am picking all the `Customer` object (that includes customer name and Id too) Then `MethodA` calls `MethodB` which picks `await customersRecords`. `MethodB` does exist in same class as `MethodA`.

I have external MyLogger class. In `MethodA` I need to assign `customerId`

```
((MyLogger)log).CustomerId = customer.Id;
```

so that It get reference for each customer. With classic loop is fine but with multithread I get sometime different values of `customerId`. I need to ensure is thread-safe

`MethodA`

```cs
public Class MethodA{

  private static ILogger log;

public MethodA(ILogger logger){
   log = logger;
} 

 public async Task<List<Customers>> MethodA(){
    List<Customer> customers = await GetAllCustomers();
    var inboundCustomerFiles= new List<InboundCustomerFiles>(); 

    await Task.WhenAll(customers.Select(async customer =>
        {
           ((MyLogger)log).CustomerId = customer.Id; // need help here...
           log.LogDebug($"@@@ Processing Customer :: {customer.Id}: 
 and Oper8 has customerId {((MyLogger)log).CustomerId} should be same in every thread!");

            var processedCustomer = await MethodB(customer);
            inboundCustomersFiles.AddRange(processedCustomer);
        });
 }
}
```

`MethodB`

```cs
public static async Task<List<InboundCustomerFiles>> MethodB(Customer customer){
    var customerRecord = await GetCustomerRecord(customerId);

    foreach(var customer in customerRecord){
         var folderLocation = await Task.Run(() => 
         getCustomerRecordFilesLocation(customerRecordId)); 
    }
    return data;
}
```

`MyLogger`

```
public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
  public string CustomerId {get; set;}
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a lock, but it would serialize all the calls.

A better approach would be to avoid shared mutable state. So either change all the methods in `MyLogger` to accept the customer Id as a parameter, and change all your logging to give this parameter. Or create new `MyLogger` objects for customer and change your code to use this object instead of the shared object.

For example, change your logger to

```
public class CustomerPrefixingLogger : ILogger
{
  private ILogger Backing {get;}
  public string CustomerId {get;}
  public CustomerPrefixingLogger(string customerId, ILogger backing){
      CustomerId = customerId;
      Backing = backing;
  }
  public void Log(int logLevel, string message) 
=> Backing.Log(logLevel, $"customer {customerId}. {message}"); 
}
```

Now the class is immutable. So if you want to create a logger with a customer Id you need to create a new object and pass this object to whatever method or class needs the logger. This solves many issues, you no longer care what type the log object is, since you will always create a new decorator. The logger is now immutable, so you do not need to care about the property changing in the middle of a call, and it helps enforce a correct design.

In general, shared mutable state of any kind will make any kind of multi threading difficult. It is far safer to use immutable objects and local variables as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks JonasH for guiding me. Do you have example in reference to above code! thanks

Comment: @Toxic Since your example does not show where the CustomerId is actually used, it is difficult to show any example

Comment: i like to understand `create new MyLogger objects for customer and change your code to use this object instead of the shared object.` in my case I am injecting MyLogger reference in `MethodA` constructor. Shall I not inject in this way?

Comment: @K.Z added an example that may help